# How do I setup a server so that pistols are the only guns allowed on maps?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Just for fun, I want to play when pistols are the only guns allowed on maps for everyone.  How can I do this?

Comment: Your question got a close vote for being a server recommendation question. I've edited the title to not sound like a recommendation question and not get it closed. Just edit the question again if my edit does not satisfy your intent.

Comment: @galacticninja thanks so much for assisting me to keep my post open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a deathmatch server with pistols only, you could try [this plugin](https://github.com/Maxximou5/csgo-deathmatch) (requires SourceMod and MetaMod).

Else, you could try using [this plugin](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=950174) to restrict weapons (also requires SourceMod and MetaMod).